# Добавить нули целому числу

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Нужно добавить ценам два нуля, если цена указана целым цислом, а не дробным.
Вот верстка

```js
$('.menu-positions-item__price_js').each(function(){
   var price = $(this).text();
   if ((price+"").indexOf(".") <= 0) {
       $(price).text($(price) + ".00");
   } 
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "menu-positions-item">
        <div class = "menu-positions-item__price"><span class = "menu-positions-item__price_js">10</span>&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
        <div class = "menu-positions-item">
        <div class = "menu-positions-item__price"><span class = "menu-positions-item__price_js">20</span>&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
        <div class = "menu-positions-item">
        <div class = "menu-positions-item__price"><span class = "menu-positions-item__price_js">22.10</span>&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
```

То есть нужно числу "10" и "20" добавить нули с точкой, а число "22.10" оставить нетронутым. Не срабатывает, менял синтаксис много раз, все никак. Кто знает как это сделать правильно?

P.S. Если что, то цены заданы ACF plugin на WordPress, если это имеет какое-то значение, в чем я сомневаюсь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$('.menu-positions-item__price_js').each(function(){
   var price = +$(this).text();
       $(this).text(price.toFixed(2));
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "menu-positions-item">
        <div class = "menu-positions-item__price"><span class = "menu-positions-item__price_js">10</span>&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
        <div class = "menu-positions-item">
        <div class = "menu-positions-item__price"><span class = "menu-positions-item__price_js">20</span></div>
    </div>
        <div class = "menu-positions-item">
        <div class = "menu-positions-item__price"><span class = "menu-positions-item__price_js">22.10</span></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так

```js
$('.menu-positions-item__price_js').each(function(){
   let price = $(this).text();
      let regExp = '[.]+';
      if(price.match(regExp) == null) {
         price += '.00';
         $(this).text(price);
      }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "menu-positions-item">
        <div class = "menu-positions-item__price"><span class = "menu-positions-item__price_js">10</span>&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
        <div class = "menu-positions-item">
        <div class = "menu-positions-item__price"><span class = "menu-positions-item__price_js">20</span>&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
        <div class = "menu-positions-item">
        <div class = "menu-positions-item__price"><span class = "menu-positions-item__price_js">22.10</span>&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Не преобразует число с одной цифрой после точки. В случае с ценой (возможно) важно целое число копеек (центов).